# Create a Material UI <DateTimePicker /> mock for testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a Material UI `<DateTimePicker />` mock for my tests, in order to be able to test the validation, to check whether an invalid date is passed. How should I go about mocking the `renderInput()` and what `params` does it expect?

```
interface MockCalendar {
    onChange: (date: string | Date) => void
}

const Calendar: FC<MockCalendar> = ({ onChange, renderInput }) => (
    <div>
        <input data-testid="calendarField" onChange={(event) => onChange(new Date(event.target.value))} />
        //what params should I pass and what should it look like?
        {renderInput && renderInput()}
    </div>
);
```

This is the MUI component implementation I'm trying to mock:

```
<DesktopDatePicker
    data-name="specialPriceActiveFrom"
    label={t('dateFrom', { ns: 'product' })}
    inputFormat={t('dateFormat', { ns: 'common' })}
    value={formik.values.specialPriceActiveFrom || null}
    onChange={(date) => {
        formik.setFieldTouched('specialPriceActiveFrom');
        formik.setFieldValue('specialPriceActiveFrom', date);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            data-testid="specialPriceActiveFrom"
            name="specialPriceActiveFrom"
            fullWidth
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            error={
                formik.touched.specialPriceActiveFrom &&
                Boolean(formik.errors.specialPriceActiveFrom)
            }
            helperText={
                formik.touched.specialPriceActiveFrom &&
                formik.errors.specialPriceActiveFrom
            }
        />
    )}
/>;
```